# Regex pattern is not correct

Tags: c#

I have the following regex to match this:
`U$MichaelU$P@$asdqwe123P@$` - this is correct; the other two are not
`U$NameU$P@$PasswordP@$`
`U$UserU$P@$ad2P@$`

A registration is valid when:

- The username is surrounded by "U$"
- The username needs to be minimum 3 characters long, start with an uppercase letter, followed only by lowercase letters
- The password is surrounded by "P@$"
- The password needs to start with minimum 5 alphabetical letters (not including digits) and must end with a digit

My regex is

```
@"^(U\S)([A-z][a-z]{3,})\1(P@\S)([a-z]{5,}[^\d])([\d]+)\3$"
```

The problem is that it matches the first one but when I submit to the judge it passes first 2 test but the rest it breaks, could you please tell me where is my mistake.

Comment: could you reformat your question?

Comment: describe a bit what you want to match

Comment: You could go and use String.Split, first with "U$" and then with "P@$" instead of a regular expression

Comment: A registration is valid when:
- The  username is surrounded by "U$"
- The username needs to be minimum 3 characters long, start with an uppercase letter, followed only by lowercase letters
- The password is surrounded by "P@$"
- The password needs to start with minimum 5 alphabetical letters (not including digits) and must end with a digit

Comment: Don't use `\S` to match a `$`. `\S` matches many other characters as well. Also, the regex looks for a minimum of 4 letters in the name, not 3, and 6 non-digits in the password, not 5.

Comment: I triend \$ but its the same result

Comment: Is the criteria that the password contains : A digit, a lowercase letter, and an uppercase letter?

Comment: I would suggest using a tool such as regex101, it will helps find mistakes in regexes like these. Based on your comments I made a [test edition](https://regex101.com/r/kQBZ6z/1)

Comment: I used exactly regex101 and thats what i manage to generate . And its killing my for the last 2 hours thats why i write here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello your regex must be

```
@"^(U\S)([A-Za-z]{3,})\1(P@\S)([A-Za-z0-9]{5,})\3$"
```

it works for you

Comment: U$NameU$P@$PasswordP@$ it count thaht one too and it dosnet have to do it

Comment: @"^(U\S)([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2,})\1(P@\S)([A-Za-z]{4,}[0-9]{1,})\3$"

you want this but it's dont count U$UserU$P@$ad2P@$

Comment: thats the one now only one test dosent pas from 12